# Issue with .NET Standard 2.0 project with Serilog assembly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a .NET Standard 2.0 project which is using Serilog assembly to log using serilog, here is project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyTitle>Logger</AssemblyTitle>
    <Description>Client Web Logger</Description>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>false</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Win32.Registry" />
    <PackageReference Include="SchneiderElectric.Software.SASigning" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="SET _WWBinDir=&quot;$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\interfaces\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\$(PlatformName)&quot;&#xD;&#xA;MKDIR %_WWBinDir%&#xD;&#xA;robocopy &quot;$(TargetDir) &quot; &quot;%_WWBinDir%&quot; InSightLogger.dll /ZB /NJH /NJS /NDL /NFL /NC /NS&#xD;&#xA;:END&#xD;&#xA;exit 0&#xD;&#xA;" />
</Target>
```

I have two other projects in my solution one is in .NET 6.0 and other one is in NET Framework 4.8
here is project files of .NET 6.0:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <Description>My Server</Description>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>3.1</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <_HasReferenceToSystemRuntime>true</_HasReferenceToSystemRuntime>
    <RootNamespace>My.Insight</RootNamespace>
    <DefineConstants>DESKTOP;LICENSEREQUIRED</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="App_Start\**" />
    <Content Remove="App_Start\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="App_Start\**" />
    <None Remove="App_Start\**" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="..\..\Common\wwwroot\Insight" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Favorites\FavoriteApiModel\FavoriteApiModel.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Logger\Logger\Logger.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\LicenseUtil\LicenseUtil.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.2.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="WWMenuHttpModule" Version="4.0.21100101" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And Framework project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>my.InSight</RootNamespace>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyTitle>Article Server Service</AssemblyTitle>
    <NeutralLanguage>en-US</NeutralLanguage>
    <Description>Article Service</Description>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="..\..\..\SharedComponents\External\StyleCop\StyleCop.Targets" />
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" />
    <PackageReference Include="StyleCop" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Logger\Logger\Logger.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Management" />
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceProcess" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration.Install" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="ProjectInstaller.cs">
        <SubType>Component</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="ProjectInstaller.Designer.cs">
        <DependentUpon>ProjectInstaller.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="myService.cs">
        <SubType>Component</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="myService.Designer.cs">
        <DependentUpon>myService.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="ProjectInstaller.resx">
        <DependentUpon>ProjectInstaller.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="myService.resx">
        <DependentUpon>myService.cs</DependentUpon>
        <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" />
</ItemGroup>
```

for .NET 6.0 all thing is working fine but for .NET Framework 4.8 it through exception when I am accessing logger projects static class and method, here is exception I am getting

```
The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.
Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\WonderWorld\MyInsight\Server\aahInSightHost.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. --Pre-bind state information --
LOG: DisplayName = netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51 
Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/WonderWorld/MyInsight/Server/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = aahInSightHost.exe
Calling assembly : Serilog, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\WonderWorld\MyInsight\Server\aahInSightHost.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Wonderware/HistorianInsight/Server/netstandard.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Wonderware/HistorianInsight/Server/netstandard/netstandard.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Wonderware/HistorianInsight/Server/netstandard.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Wonderware/HistorianInsight/Server/netstandard/netstandard.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

**Note:** only one thing I noted that I created netstandard2.0 project and in logs it is mentioned that netstandard 2.1.0.0 is searching for, but could not understand.

Comment: _Some_ dependency is asking for .NET Standard 2.1, while .NET Framework only supports 2.0. Go find out which dependency that is and upgrade it (if the developers fixed it) or downgrade to a version that targets 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By closely investigating your project files I came to know that you are using **dotnet standard 2.0** but in error it searches from **dotnet standard 2.1** so you need to verify all projects with used package version and use appropriate one.